# Mysql: Conditions on a unique primary key tuple

Tags: mysql

**Short**
Is it possible, that if I have a unique primary key tuple `(idUser,idRep)` that for each idUser `n` only certain combinations with `idRep` are possible?
For example that the following groups of keys are allowed:

(n,1);(n,2);(n,3) OR (n,1);(n,6) OR (n,2);(n,5) OR (n,4);(n,3) OR (n,7)

but not the keys (n,1) and (n,7) together?

**Long question**

I have the following table

```
 idUser | idGroup | idType |
```

where the primary key is `(idUser,idGroup)`. There are three different values for idGroup: `1,2,3`. For almost all users the idType is always the same independent of the group, but there are a few exceptions. Thus the table looks like that

```
idUser | idGroup | idType 
--------------------------
   1   |    1    |   43
   1   |    2    |   43
   1   |    3    |   43
   2   |    1    |   22
   2   |    2    |   22
   3   |    1    |   12
   3   |    3    |   12
   4   |    2    |   5
   4   |    3    |   6
```

I thought I could avoid the redundancy with a column idRep which contains the information in which groups one user is as follows

> 1 -> user is in group 1
>
> 2 -> user is in group 2
>
> 3 -> user is in group 1 and 2  (1+2=3)
>
> 4 -> user is in group 3
>
> 5 -> user is in group 1 and 3 (4+1=5)
>
> 6 -> user is in group 2 and 3 (4+2=6)
>
> 7 -> user is in group 1 and 2 and 3 (4+2+1=7)

this would reduce redundancy and the above table would shrink to

```
 idUser | idRep  | idType
-------------------------
   1   |    7    |   43
   2   |    3    |   22
   3   |    5    |   12
   4   |    2    |   5
   4   |    4    |   6
```

However the disadvantage is that its possible that even if `(idUser,idRep)` is a primary key there is the possibility of a wrong entry like

```
 idUser | idRep  | idType
-------------------------
   1   |    7    |   43
   1   |    1    |   42
```

In this case, there is a contradiction about idType for idUser  `1` in group `1`.

So my question is: Is it possible to say that for a specific idUser `n` only the following groups of keys are allowed:

(n,1);(n,2);(n,3) OR (n,1);(n,6) OR (n,2);(n,5) OR (n,4);(n,3) OR (n,7)

but not for (n,1) and (n,7)?

Comment: I don't think you  can do this with MySQL constraints.  You would need a trigger.

Comment: In other rdbms products you would use the `check` constraint to achieve the described output. Unfortunately, MySQL does not enforce check constraints, so you need to use a trigger, as @GordonLinoff said.

Comment: Well, you could constuct a whitelist (and/or a blacklist) of combinations as a separate table.